# Interrupt current thread inside run() doesn't throw InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, interrupt-handling

I made a simple function to test `interrupt()` & `InterruptedException` in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    checkInterrupt();

}

private static void checkInterrupt() {
        Runnable runMe = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                    System.out.println("i = "+i);
                    if(i==3) {
                        System.out.println("i==3, Thread = "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                        //I invoke interrupt() on the working thread.
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }

            }

        };

        Thread workingThread = new Thread(runMe);
        System.out.println("workingThread("+workingThread.getId()+") interrupted 1 ? "+workingThread.isInterrupted());
        workingThread.start();
        try {
            workingThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //I thought I should get InterruptedException, but I didn't, why?
            System.out.println("workingThread("+workingThread.getId()+") is interrupted.");

        }

        System.out.println("workingThread("+workingThread.getId()+") interrupted 2 ? "+workingThread.isInterrupted());

    }
```

As you see above, in run(), I interrupt the working thread by invoking `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` when `i==3`.  I thought my code should catch `InterruptedException` during `workingThread.join()`. But there is no exception at all. Why?

Comment: The exception is thrown only in the thread being interrupted. Your main thread has not been interrupted -> no exception.

Comment: Looking at the answers, everybody here is explaining what your code actually does, but what is it that you _want_ it to do?  Are you trying to solve a problem? or are you just trying to learn something about how Java threads work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get an `InterruptedException` if the thread calling `join` is interrupted while waiting for the other one to die. That's not what happens in your case - you're interrupting *the thread you're joining* which is an entirely different matter.

Comment: It is not clear to me still. I have interrupted working thread , and working thread is calling join().

Comment: Working thread is not calling `join()`. You are confusing the `Thread` object with the actual thread of execution. You have called `workingThread.join()` **from the main thread**.

Comment: Ok, Got your point, thanks! I removed the join() part in my code, but in run() I have Thread.currentThread().interrupt(), isn't it interrupting my working thread? But there is no InterruptedException throwing though.

Comment: @user842225: I would expect it to be interrupted when it next does IO. What are you observing?

Comment: It is interrupting it. Now call an *interruptible method* from the same thread and you'll receive your exception. This is a minimal example to get the exception: `Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); Thread.currentThread().join();`. You don't even need two threads.

Comment: @Marko, **After** `join()`, I added the code `workingThread.isInterrupted()` it returns false. Does it mean isInterrupted() clear the interrupt status of working thread?

Comment: @user842225: No, but it's possible that the thread terminating clears the interrupt status... that's my guess as to what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You are interrupting the wrong thread.  From the documentation of `Thread.join()`:

> InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread.

You are interupting the thread that is being joined, not the thread that is doing the joining (referred to as current thread in the documentation).

Try this instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {}
        }
    };

    t.start();

    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    t.join();

}
```

Here is another variant, this time interrupting from the thread that is being joined.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                mainThread.interrupt();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();

    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Ok, if forget about the join() from my code for a moment. Am I right that in my run() function the code Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  is interrupting the working thread ?

Comment: @user842225 yes, that is correct. And that is why I have pulled the reference to the mainThread out as a final variable in my example above. It is the mainThread that needs to be interrupted in order to see the exception at the join(), and not the working thread.